# How can I change a single file from an UBI image

Tags: ubifs

I have an ubi image file (.ubi) and I want to change a single file from that image (`/etc/network/interfaces` to be precise).

How can I change a single file from that ubi image?

I'm using OS X but I have a Ubuntu VM as well.

Comment: It seems no difference between ubifs images and images of other fs: unpack image or mount-loop exists image, make some changes and rebuild finally image. I found this link and hope this will be helpful for you - http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/3394-extract-and-rebuild-a-ubi-image/.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Thank you. I already had a look at this link and got stuck because `mtdblockmodprobe` and `ubimodprobe` wasn't found by modprobe.

Comment: Oh I see now that this is most likely a formatting error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after a lot of reading, I finally figured it out how to do it on Ubuntu:

1.) Simulate a NAND MT-device with `nandsim`

```
modprobe nandsim first_id_byte=... second_id_byte=.. third_id_byte=.. fourth_id_byte=...
```

[List of NAND chip IDs.](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/nand-data/nanddata.html)

2.) Find out the MT-device id

```
cat /proc/mtd | grep -i "NAND Simulator"
```

3.) Load UBI kernel module

```
modprobe ubi
```

4.) Erase MT-device (you may skip this step)

```
flash_erase /dev/mtdX 0 0
```

5.) Flash the UBI image with `ubiformat`

```
ubiformat /dev/mtdX -y -f /path/to/ubi -O XXXX -s XXXX
```

6.) Attach MT-device to UBI with `ubiattach` and note the UBI device number

```
ubiattach -p /dev/mtdX
```

7.) Mount it with `mount`

```
mount -t ubifs ubiX /path/to/mount-point/
```

8.) Make the changes.

9.) Create UBIFS with `mkfs.ubifs`

```
mkfs.ubifs -o ubifs.img -m XXXX -e XXXX -c XXXX -v -r /path/to/mount-point/
```

10.) Create UBI image with `ubinize`

```
ubinize -o final.ubi -p XXXX -m XXXX -s XXXX -v ubinize.cfg
```

---

`XXXX` = Parameter that is specific to the NAND flash chip used.

`ubinize.cfg` looks something like this:

```
[rootfs]
mode=ubi
image=ubifs.img
vol_name=rootfs
vol_flags=autoresize
vol_type=dynamic
vol_id=0
```